# How to UPDATE Table A from Table B when only shared data is in Table C?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

## What I have

I have three tables MySQL tables: `Folder`, `Application` and `MemberInFolder`.

**Folder**

- id
- jobId

**MemberInFolder**

- id
- folderId
- applicationId (new)

**Application**

- id
- jobId

## What I want to do

I want to populate the column `MemberInFolder.applicationId` with the the `Application.id` where `MemberInFolder.folderId=Folder.id AND Folder.jobId=Application.jobId`.

## The problem

I can't figure out how to construct an `UPDATE` query which actually does what I want. I suppose I should use `JOIN`s, but so far I've managed nothing but errors.

Are there any bright minds who could help me?

Comment: Show the code you've tried so far, quote any errors in full, and show sample desired vs current output.

Comment: Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Thanks @Strawberry! Will make sure to keep this in mind for future posts. Got a good answer from JShark though, so I won't update this post with any samples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
UPDATE MemberInFolder M
JOIN Folder F on M.FolderID = F.ID
JOIN Application A on A.jobID = F.jobID
SET M.ApplicationID = A.ID
```

Comment: I believe this should do the trick, yes, thank you! Horribly slow, still chewing one hour later, but that's only to be expected with lots of data. Should have tried it on a sample database first.

Comment: UPDATEs can be very slow some things which can help: 1) Running in batches;2)Disabling indexes during UPDATE; 3)Indexing the underlying tables; 4) Splitting into two steps: first select just the data you need into a staging table (JOINS as above but SELECT M.folderID, A.ID) and then run a simple update just joining MemberInFolder to your staging table on M.FolderID = STG.FolderID, and SET M.ApplicationID = STG.ID.